# Using shared_memory with Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing, shared-memory

In our application we have a stream of data coming out of a LoRa transceiver which I want to be read by only one main process. Nevertheless, I would like to be able to process this data by separate processes in order not to slow down the main process so it keeps receiving and sending messages to four transmitters which read sensor data. The main process (the 'coordinator') and the separate processes will be running in a Raspberry Pi 4.

I want to keep all these process alive all the time and be able to share memory with the coordinator, which unrolls the bytes of every incoming message and saves them on n different pandas dataframes, one for every subprocess that will be reading them. In this case we'd have 4 transmitters, 4 streams of data to be managed by the coordinator, 4 pandas dataframes in the coordinator, 4 processes running and processing the data, which is already stored in the coordinator's dataframes. I have four questions regarding this subject, which I hoped you could help me with. I tried to organize the questions relative to their importance for me. The biggest deal is being able to declare the DataFrames properly and be able to share them(1 and 4.2). Simultaneous read/write would be second (2) and dynamic memory allocation would be last (points 3 and 4.1). I'm sorry for the long post and I hope you could help me with at least some of it. Thank you!

**1st question**

By reading the docs, I can see that I could create a sufficiently large, fixed size dataframe which is rolled in order to keep the newest data in the end, so i believe this is not an issue. Nevertheless, when connecting to this DataFrame from another process, I see that there is the need for defining it's type and  size. These small subprocesses might die and live and could join the coordinator's memory by reading the shared memory name from a file written by the coordinator just after the creation of the empty dataframes.

This comes from the docs(https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html):

```
>>>...(this is happening in another process after shared memory with name 'psm_21467_46075' has already been created)
>>> existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name='psm_21467_46075')
>>> # Note that a.shape is (6,) and a.dtype is np.int64 in this example
>>> c = np.ndarray((6,), dtype=np.int64, buffer=existing_shm.buf)
```

When c is created in the second process, its size and type must be declared, as well as its name. In the example it is a numpy array but, how would the declaration change for a pandas dataframe?

**2nd question**

This pandas Dataframe will be created as follows: first column has a timestamp, second to n column will have sensor values and the last (`n+1`) column will have a flag. I intend to change this flag from the subprocesses in order to know which part of the incoming buffer has already been processed. With each new packet, the coordinator rolls up the old data and sets the end of the dataframe with fresh data with a 'false' *processed* flag.

In order to keep the position in the DataFrame monitored I would have an integer value `posInDf` that measures where the *not processed yet* data starts. So the subprocess reads the dataframe from this position (let's call it `a`) until the end (`m`), brings this data (`n+1 x m-a` dataframe) to a local copy (because the coordinator will be continuously bringing new data in), makes operations on them, saves them in a csv (for backup), uploads that to a server and, at the end, changes the flag in the coordinator's DataFrame.

In this scenario,

1. Do you believe trying to write from the coordinator and the subprocesses to the same correspondent Dataframe (one dataframe assigned to every subprocess) at the same time (but different columns) would bring conflicts in memory?
2. If the DataFrame is continuosly moving, how would you edit the flags correctly in order not to lose the reference given by `posInDf` (value of `posInDf` gets read by the subprocess in a line and the next line will assign m-a elements from the DataFrame counting from `posInDef` with a True *processed* flag) because of the time elapsed between lines? Doing this edit in one line would suffice (accesing both the DataFrame and the current `posInDef` value simultaneously)?

**3rd question**

I'm defining a fixed size DataFrame in the coordinator but I don't know if it might be possible to make it variable in size. New data comes in, gets written in the top of the DataFrame and starts getting old by falling down with new packets coming. The subprocess could read the DataFrame from its last element (the bottom) until the first or second and *trim* this data. When new packets come, the DataFrame will populate again but it will get constantly trimmed.

Is it possible to do this using shared_memory from multiprocessing? If possible, would this be more or less efficient than the first approach?

**4th question**

By means of a configuration list sent from a subprocess (from an instruction caught from internet) to the coordinator, there could be a request that the coordinator asks more or less variables than it has been receiving until now to the transmitter it is already receiving data from. In this case, the DataFrame columns will need to grow or shrink as a function of this number of variables.

1. Under this scenario and taking into account the previous question, would it be possible to reallocate the space from the DataFrame so the subprocesses don't lose the reference of the shared memory location? or,
2. Will it be needed to create a new DataFrame in the coordinator,
   save its name in file, give a signal to the corresponding
   transmitter that the DataFrame has changed address, make the
   subprocess connect to the new one and close the connection to the
   last one?

Once again: any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you hoping to make the pandas DataFrame be a *view* of the underlying shared memory, like you do with your numpy array?  I don't think that is possible (although it would be very cool if it were possible).

Comment: Hello Nicholas! Yes, but more than a view, as a shared object for all related processes... In case it was not possible, would you recommend then sticking to a numpy array instead of a Dataframe? In this case, Do you know about their behavior (numpy arrays) in dynamically allocated shared memory?